# reading file with multiple columns

Tags: c++, iostream

I have a file named file.dat which has three columns and numbers stored in them. File content look as follows

```
2.30276e-07 1.73472e-18 -2.31198e-07
6.94031e-07 1.99493e-17 -2.30956e-07
1.15043e-06 -6.93889e-18 -2.25137e-07
1.58577e-06 -8.67362e-19 -2.12817e-07
1.99688e-06 1.64799e-17 -1.94697e-07
2.39116e-06 -5.20417e-18 -1.98568e-07
2.76304e-06 3.46945e-18 -1.7162e-07
3.06033e-06 -2.60209e-17 -1.24218e-07
3.25685e-06 -1.47451e-17 -7.85356e-08
```

I need to read the file and store the column numbers in them.

```
std::string s;
std::ifstream in("file.dat");

double a[10], b[10],c[10] ;
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
std::getline(in, s);
s >>a[i] >>b[i] >>c[i] ;
}
```

But with this I get error as

```
flux.cpp:117:7: error: no match for ‘operator>>’ in ‘s >> aa’
flux.cpp:117:7: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.tcc:998:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/istream.tcc:957:5: note: template<class _CharT2, class _Traits2> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, _CharT2*)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/istream.tcc:925:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, _CharT&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:709:5: note: template<class _Traits> std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>&, unsigned char&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:714:5: note: template<class _Traits> std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>&, signed char&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:756:5: note: template<class _Traits> std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>&, unsigned char*)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:761:5: note: template<class _Traits> std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>&, signed char*)
```

How I can read numbers from file correctly?

Comment: You need to #include `<string>` and `<fstream>`.  Also, there is no operator >> defined for `std::string`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie [Yes there is.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt)

Comment: @0x499602D2 _' Yes there is.'_ Of course not in the sense it's used in the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"How I can read numbers from file correctly?"*

`std::string` doesn't provide that `operator>>`, as you're trying to use it. Use a [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) instead

```
 std::getline(in, s);
 istringstream iss(s);
 iss >>a[i] >>b[i] >>c[i] ;
```

Also don't forget the right `#include` statements.

---

As your file only contains `double` values, you could also consider to omit the `getline()` completely. You could just write a loop as follows

```
for(int = 0; i < 10 && in >>a[i] >>b[i] >>c[i]; ++i);
```

Comment: You should search StackOverflow first.  There are too many of these already: https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow+c%2B%2B+read+columns+from+file&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb

Comment: @ThomasMatthews _'There are too many of these already'_ Yes, but it's hard to select on as _"The Dupe"_ here :P ...

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do

```
std::ifstream in("file.dat");

double a[10], b[10],c[10] ;
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    in >>a[i] >>b[i] >>c[i] ;
}
```

, because `istream`'s `operator>>` skips over line breaks just as it would over spaces by default.